# python list comprehension doesn't work when converted to nested for loops

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand this snippet from [itertools library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

What this function does is that it takes two arguments: a set of characters and a length of the output, then generates all possible permutations using the given set of characters. for example:

```
product('ab', repeat=3)
#produces
['a','a','a'],
['a','a','b'],
['a','b','a'],
['a','b','b'],
['b','a','a'],
['b','a','b'],
['b','b','a'],
['b','b','b']
```

all make sense to me except for this line:

```
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

i tried to uncompact it to normal for loops:

```
for pool in pools:
    for x in result:
        for y in pool:
            result.append(x+[y])
```

But i ended up with infinite loop!

How does it work?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614004/how-do-i-convert-pythons-itertools-product-library-from-a-list-comprehension-to?rq=1

Comment: yah almost same question, i didn't see it before i posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You got the translation right. But in

```
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

you create a list, using `result` and `pool`, and then assign it to `result`.

In

```
for pool in pools:
    for x in result:
        for y in pool:
            result.append(x+[y])
```

you iterate over result (`for x in result`), and add elements to it, so it keeps growing.

If you want to create for loops, you can use a temporary variable to save the previous `result`, and build the new one:

```
for pool in pools:
    result2 = result[:]
    result = []
    for x in result2:
        for y in pool:
            result.append(x+[y])
```

Edit: Thanks to @razzak and @GregHewgill for correcting my mistakes

Comment: this doesn't produce the same result, shouldn't `result2 = result[:]` be placed inside one of the nested loops?

Comment: You'll also have to set `result = []` before you start appending to it (before the first `for` loop).

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks it worked i put `result2 = result[:]` and `result = []` inside `for pool in pools` and i got the same result as the original snippet